# having difficulty in saving user data through Jmeter(using csv data set config)

Tags: testing, jmeter

I have recorded a scenario of saving user data in a form using J meter, where partial data is already filled up and remaining data, it is picking up from CSV file.when i am running the script, i can see in the request section, that j meter is able to pick data from CSV but some how it is not submitting along with HTTP request..which i have seen in response of the same HTTP request.response code shows  those columns empty where i wanted to fill data via j meter.i am kinda new..i need help in this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
2. Execute the request in browser
3. Execute the request in JMeter
4. Compare the requests in the sniffer tool - **the requests should be exactly the same** (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)), if the requests are the same - you should get the same response, if they are not - you need to amend JMeter's configuration so it would send the same request as the browser does.

The variables originated from the CSV Data Set Config (as well as other [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) including [pre-defined ones](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)) can be observed using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)